# Turning strings in a list into floats

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point

I have created a function that sorts through a csv file and returns lists into tuples however the items in the lists are string, how do I convert them to floats?

I need to do calculations with this data such as mean, median etc.

```
def load_data(filename):
    datasets = []
    for line in open(filename):
        line = line.strip().split(",")
        dataset = ((line[0],line[1:]))
        datasets.append(dataset)

    return datasets
```

At the moment my data looks like this when printed `('Slow Loris', [' 21.72', ' 29.3', ' 20.08', ' 29.98',......` etc how do I remove the `'  '` around the numbers

Comment: [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float)

Comment: mostly unrelated to the `float` issue, but you may want to consider using python's builtin [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for parsing the csv file instead of doing it yourself as it will be a bit more robust.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse String to Float or Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def load_data(filename):
    datasets = []
    for line in open(filename):
        line = line.strip().split(",")    
        floats = [float(x) for x in line[1:]]
        dataset = ((line[0],floats))
        datasets.append(dataset)
    return datasets
```

Comment: I think in this case, the first element in the tuple is a string and trying to cast as a float will give a `ValueError`.  Probably want something like `dataset = (dataset[0], [float(x) for x in dataset[1])` instead

Comment: Or even ```dataset = ((line[0],map(float,line[1:])))```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new list and append the casted type like so...

```
list_of_floats = list()
for item in list_of_strings:
    list_of_floats.append(float(item))
```

Or iterate through each value and change it at its current position...

```
for i in range(len(list_of_strings)):
    list_of_strings[i] = float(list_of_strings)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the float() function to typecast it as a float.

Per this link: [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Comment: ```float()``` **function**.